# Using a String for an instance object name

Tags: java

I have this code which gets info from an other class but I have to add another line other code for every instance object.

```
public static int giveShipData(String shipName,int Data){
    if(shipName.equals("Player")){i = Player.getData(Data);}
    return i;
}
```

Is it possible to have something like:

```
public static int giveShipData(String shipName,int Data){
    i = shipName.getData(Data);
    return i;
}
```

Sorry if I am using the wrong terminology I am self taught and new.

Comment: is `Player#getData` a static class method that receives an `int` and returns another `int`?

Comment: `i = shipName.getData(Data);` is wrong. `shipName` is instance of `String` class and haven't `getData` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd better to reconsider your design. If you have a ship name and ship data I assume you must have a Ship class which looks something like this:

```
public class Ship {
    private String name;
    private int data;

    public Ship(String name, int data) {
        this.name = name;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

Besides this class there should be a class like `Shipyard`:

```
 public class Shipyard {
    private Map<String, Ship> shipsByNameMap = new HashMap<String, Ship>();

    public void registerShipByName(String name, Ship ship){
        shipsByNameMap.put(name, ship);
    }

    public Ship getShipByName(String name){
        return shipsByNameMap.get(name);
    }
}
```

So, at first you invoke shipyard.getShip("Player") method to get `ship` object, than you can invoke `ship.getData()` method to retrieve ship data.

Comment: Thanks this seems to do exactly what I want.

Comment: +1 for Shipyard.  :-)  And for an excellent example of OOP.  Suggestion:  if `registerShipByName` takes two params, then the second could be the `data`. That way it could create a new `Ship` and then register it.  If the `Ship` already exists, then `registerShipByName` needs only the `Ship` param, and it can get the `name` from the `Ship`.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do something like this...

```
int[] ships = new int[3]; // 3 ships

public void populateShips(){
  for (int i=0;i<ships.length;i++){
    ships[i] = giveShipData(shipname,data);
    }
  }

public int giveShipData(String shipName,int data){
    return shipName.getData(data);
}
```

This would allow you to create any number of ships, just increase the size of the `ships[]` array to be however many ships you want.

Is this kinda what you're after?

Comment: I would be nice if I didn't have to do this but this will work thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code "shipName" is a string...and it does not have getData() method. And why are you passing Data to the getData()... You could instead write something like this-

```
 i = ClassObj.getData(shipname);
```

and in the method getData return the info regarding the "shipname".